# Pandas - How to query multiple columns with single variable

Tags: pandas, dataframe, filter

I would like to query multiple columns from a single input.

The following will only query the first column 'Drug Name' but ignores 'BP'.

```
filtered = df.query("(`Drug Name` in @search) or (BP in @search)")
```

Doesn't give any errors either.

Comment: kindly provide sample data with expected output

Comment: Apologies, I have messed this question up, it was working. I was expecting a different result. I thought the query would have returned the @search variable if contained somewhere within the entry but its only returning a result with explicit match.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for a single value in two columns

```
df = DataFrame({
    'DN':['abc', 'efg'],
    'BP':['efg','xyz']
})

df.query('("efg" in DN) or ("efg" in BP)')
```

More than one elements in a single columns:

```
df.query('["abc", "efg"] in DN')
```

**In your example**
if 'DrugName' and 'BP' are column names and we want to search 'search' string.

**Input**

```
df = DataFrame({
    'DrugName':['abc', 'efg', 'search'],
    'BP':['efg','search','xyz']
})

    DrugName    BP
0   abc         efg
1   efg         search
2   search      xyz
```

**Code**

```
df.query('("search" in DrugName) or ("search" in BP)')
```

**Output**

```
    DrugName    BP
1   efg         search
2   search      xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this?

```
filtered = df.query("('Drug Name' in @search) and ('BP' not in @search)")
```